# How can I set one key on keyboard for multiple keys?

Tags: keyboard

What I want is that if I press 'U' in window-7/10 then it must act as 'I+O' that is the input to PC should be pressing of 'I' and 'O' together when 'U' would be pressed.

The reason I want this is because I want to make Tekken 3 moves easy. I want to do this only temporarily.

Answer (score 2):

The software [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) should be able to do that kind of key remapping.

Comment: I've downloaded it but it is quite technical to use. I am not able to figure out how it works.

Comment: @user31782 - I'm not familiar with Autohotkey myself, but [chapter 3](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Tutorial.htm#s3) of its tutorial shows what you need. It should be `u::send i,o`